# All programs non-responsive after hibernation in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, sleep, hibernate

I'm having issues waking my Windows 7, 64 bit system from hibernation.  Here's what happened and what I've tried to solve the issue:

1. have been successfully hibernating and waking this PC for many years
2. was trying to speed up performance and tried disabling some services via "msconfig" (bad idea, it seems)
3. now all programs become non-responsive when the PC wakes from hibernation.  It does not seem program-specific and I cannot start a new process via the Task Manager.
4. all programs are non-responsive in the same way after waking from sleep as well.
5. Everything works fine with *either* a full restart or just logging off and logging back in through the same account.

Steps I've take to try to fix:

1. re-enable all services/startup via msconfig - intriguingly, this causes the programs to be responsive again for ~1 minute, before they all freeze again
2. disable/re-enable hibernation via command prompt to delete hiberfil.sys - no difference; still hangs on waking.
3. ran the system file checker via SFC /scannow - no corrupt files found; still hangs on waking.
4. tried a clean boot of the system - problem still persists in this mode.
5. chkdsk result is no problems found

Any help with this issue is much appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the hibernation file?  Boot to WinRE/WinPE, issue at terminal: `del C:\hiberfile.sys`.  Verify (1) it's been removed, and (2) that C: is the normal Windows partition since WinPE/RE usually assigns a different drive letter to the Windows partition, via `dir c:\ `.  While you're at it, also delete the pagefile: `del c:\pagefile.sys`.  You may have to also specify the `/A` [attributes] parameter for hidden and system files... I can't recall for sure (see `del /?`).

Comment: Easier way is to do it from command prompt while in Windows: powercfg -h off

Comment: Then enable it again, powercfg -h on

Comment: Thanks for the replies.

No difference after deleting hyberfil.sys.  I have tried this a couple times to no avail.  

I edited my response above to note that the computer is similarly unresponsive after waking from sleep.  Does this suggest something outside of issues w/ hyberfil.sys?

Comment: Rollback to a System Restore point from before you did those optimizations.

Comment: I looked and the only restore points that precede this are several years old and, unfortunately, would require me to reinstall/reupdate a lot of elements on my system.  

I just noted this morning that logging off of the computer is sufficient to get everything back to a working state.  Not sure if that adds anything useful to this discussion.